# How to create layers of arrays (arrays in arrays) with given sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create arrays in arrays in an array in a flexible way. The question is probably best illustrated by an example.

We want to construct an array with three layers. The size of each layer are given by the following:

```
S1, S2, S3 = 3, [3,2,2], 4
```

Each constant represent a size of the array I want to construct. S1 represents the outer layer and corresponds to len(S2). S2 represents the next layer where each must have a size corresponding to that element in the list. Lastly, S3 represents the size of each array in the innermost layer.

I know one way to do this.

```
V = np.array([ 
np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]), 
np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]),
np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]) 
])
```

But this is quite impractical if either S1 or S2 changes. How do you create such an array for any S1 and S2 as efficiently as possible?

I hope the question made some sense. If not, I will do my best to expand or reformulate the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So S1 really is duplicate information, since `S1 == len(S2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what your `V` expression created:

```
In [3]: V
Out[3]: 
array([ array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])], dtype=object)
In [4]: V.shape
Out[4]: (3,)
In [5]: V[0].shape
Out[5]: (3, 4)
In [6]: V[1].shape
Out[6]: (2, 4)
In [7]: V[2].shape
Out[7]: (2, 4)
```

It's a 3 element object type array.  The elements are 2d float arrays.

If I changed the first subarray to contain just 2 arrays, I get a 3d array

```
In [11]: V1 = np.array([ 
    ...: np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]), 
    ...: np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]),
    ...: np.array([np.zeros(S3), np.zeros(S3)]) 
    ...: ])
In [12]: V1.shape
Out[12]: (3, 2, 4)
```

Constructing arrays of arrays is tricky because `np.array` tries to construct an multidimensional array rather than a ragged object array.

`@trincot's` nested list is more predictable

```
In [15]: L1 = [[[0]*S3 for _ in range(size)] for size in S2]
In [16]: L1
Out[16]: 
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Often object dtype arrays of arrays are a pain to construct, and rarely offer processing advantages over similar lists.

Throw in a few `array` wrappers and that nested list comprehension replicates your `V`:

```
A3 = np.array([np.array([np.zeros(S3) for _ in range(size)]) for size in S2])
```

It generalizes your `V` expression but does not improve on it.

To ensure that I had 3 array layers I'd have to make a construction like:

```
In [25]: A1=np.zeros((S1,),object)
In [27]: for i,n in enumerate(S2):
    ...:     A = np.zeros((n,), object)
    ...:     for j in range(n):
    ...:         A[j]=np.zeros(S3)
    ...:     A1[i]=A 
In [28]: A1
Out[28]: 
array([ array([array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
       array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object),
       array([array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object),
       array([array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object)], dtype=object)
In [29]: A1.shape
Out[29]: (3,)
In [30]: A1[0].shape
Out[30]: (3,)
In [31]: A1[0][0].shape
Out[31]: (4,)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
[[[0]*s3 for _ in range(size)] for size in s2]
```

`s1` is really not needed as information, since `s1 == len(s2)`.

Comment: I added the S1 just to clarity. But this work, thanks. I guess I was just too worked by making the numpy arrays, when there actually was a very easy way for doing this using lists.